# Have problem making SQL table on Apex Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm making two tables, `STUDENT` and `STUDENTREPORT`. I made `STUDENT`, but not the other. I ran the code, but it says missing or invalid option.

My `STUDENTREPORT` command:

[image]

Comment: paste your code and error message as text , avoid the screenshot for code , sample data and error messages

Comment: If you define the FC constraint inline as `s_id references student (s_id)` then you won't need two separate statements.

Answer (score 4):

Both commands are correctly written, they execute OK in e.g. SQL*Plus or SQL Developer:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE studentreport (
  2      sr_number      VARCHAR2(5),
  3      sr_rade        VARCHAR2(5),
  4      sr_semester    VARCHAR2(5),
  5      class_attended NUMBER,
  6      s_id           VARCHAR2(5),
  7      PRIMARY KEY ( sr_number )
  8          USING INDEX enable
  9  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE studentreport
  2      ADD FOREIGN KEY ( s_id )
  3          REFERENCES student ( s_id )
  4      ENABLE;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

But, in Oracle Apex' **SQL Workshop**, you can execute only one command at a time. Therefore:

- remove `alter table` (delete it from the editor) so that you'd first execute `create table`; then delete that statement and execute `alter table`, or
- select (with a mouse, so that text *turns blue*) `create table` and hit RUN to execute it; then select `alter table` and execute it with RUN

That's just how SQL Workshop behaves, there's nothing you can do about it (at least, I don't know what you *could/should* do, apart from what I already said).

Comment: I make a SQL Script with all the statements and run the script. Maybe not best way to do it, but only way I found to run more than one SQL command at once.

Comment: Sure, why not. Though, if you're running Apex on your own database (not necessarily installed on your PC, but available to you as you're in the same network) and not the one on apex.oracle.com or any other site that allows access to your schema only via SQL Workshop, then consider to download and install Oracle's **SQL Developer** free GUI tool which lets you work way easier. SQL Workshop is OK if you don't have anything better, I'd say.

Comment: yeah, at work we use Toad for Oracle. When messing around on apex.oracle.com workspace i use SQL scripts. sorry should have specified. I will download SQL Developer and try that out when working on personal laptop. Thanks for suggestion.